# ElasticSearch refresh effect on cache

Tags: caching, elasticsearch

In ElasticSearch, does calling [Refresh](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-refresh.html) or [Flush](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-flush.html) clear field and filter cache?

I have a write-heavy application, is it better to run refresh or flush, or is there any better approach for this?

Comment: how do you solve this finally?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A refresh causes new documents to be visible for searching. This happens by writing a new index segment.  A new segment can also be made by merging old large ones.

Filter- and field caches are managed per segment, since a segment is immutable. You can use the warmer APIs to ensure caches are pre-warmed before being made available for search. If not, then *parts* of the cache is essentially "cleared".

A `flush` in Elasticsearch terms actually calls a Lucene `commit`. This is quite more expensive.

If you have a write heavy app, you probably want to increase the refresh interval to get better indexing throughput.

There's some more details about these things in these two articles:

- [Elasticsearch from the Bottom Up, Part 1](https://www.found.no/foundation/elasticsearch-from-the-bottom-up/)
- [Elasticsearch Refresh Interval vs Indexing Performance](http://blog.sematext.com/2013/07/08/elasticsearch-refresh-interval-vs-indexing-performance/)

Comment: If I understand correctly: (1) refresh will clear (part) of the cache. (2) flush will clear -all- the cache. (3) optimize will also clear all the cache since it merges all the segments.

Am I correct?

Comment: Refresh and optimize both cause new segments without warm caches to be added. Thus the warmer API. Flush makes sure everything is safely persisted to disk, it does not cause clearing of caches. The only thing that entirely clears the caches is the _clear-API. Elasticsearch does it best to keep as much as possible of the caches valid.

Comment: A follow-up to this question: would increasing `refresh_interval` improve query and aggregation performance (presumably b/c they rely on the cache)?